# Accessing a structure in vertex shader from the code in WebGl

Tags: structure, webgl, vertex-shader

How can I reach this light structure in my vertex shader?

```
struct LightInfo {
    vec4 Position; // Light position in eye coords.
    vec3 La; // Ambient light intensity
    vec3 Ld; // Diffuse light intensity
    vec3 Ls; // Specular light intensity
};
uniform LightInfo Light;
```

I tried:

```
shaderProgram.Light = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Light");
```

which compiles, but when I try to insert some value like:

```
gl.uniform4f(
    shaderProgram.Light.Position,
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionX").value),
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionY").value),
    parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightPositionZ").value),
    0.0
);
```

It breaks completely. How would one send this position data into a shader structure?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you must get a location for each base type. In your example

```c
struct LightInfo {
    vec4 Position; // Light position in eye coords.
    vec3 La; // Ambient light intensity
    vec3 Ld; // Diffuse light intensity
    vec3 Ls; // Specular light intensity
};
uniform LightInfo Light;
```

Means you need

```js
var lightPosLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Light.Position");
var lightLaLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Light.La");
var lightLdLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Light.Ld");
var lightLsLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Light.Ls");
```

If you have arrays you'd need locations for each field of each array as in

```c
struct LightInfo {
    vec4 Position; // Light position in eye coords.
    vec3 La; // Ambient light intensity
    vec3 Ld; // Diffuse light intensity
    vec3 Ls; // Specular light intensity
};
uniform LightInfo Lights[2];
```

```js
var light0PosLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Position");
var light0LaLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].La");
var light0LdLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Ld");
var light0LsLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Ls");
var light1PosLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Position");
var light1LaLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].La");
var light1LdLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Ld");
var light1LsLoc  = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Ls");
```

And arrays of arrays etc.

```c
struct LightInfo {
    vec4 Positions[2]; // Light positions in eye coords.
    vec3 La; // Ambient light intensity
    vec3 Ld; // Diffuse light intensity
    vec3 Ls; // Specular light intensity
};
uniform LightInfo Lights[2];
```

```js
var light0Pos0Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Positions[0]");
var light0Pos1Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Positions[1]");
var light0LaLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].La");
var light0LdLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Ld");
var light0LsLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[0].Ls");
var light1Pos0Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Positions[0]");
var light1Pos1Loc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Positions[1]");
var light1LaLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].La");
var light1LdLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Ld");
var light1LsLoc   = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "Lights[1].Ls");
```

etc...

Comment: This would be the best explanation possible. Thank you.